# Movimiento de layout indeseado

Tags: java, android

Tengo una actividad con un **ViewPager** y 2 fragmentes acoplados a el. Al final de esa activity quiero poner un boton que diga registrar y sea el que me manda al segundo fragment. El problema es que al hacer foco en un **EditText** dentro del **ViewPager** me sube tambien

> Esto es parte del xml del ViewPager es el que me esta dando el comportamiento indeseado

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/registerLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_account" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/signUp_Button"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Regístrate" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Les dejo un screenshot para que me entiendan.

[image: Observen el textView de nuevo por aqui donde esta]

Quiero que se quede donde esta. Asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba añadiendo android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de poner `focusableInTouchMode="false"` en donde no queres, mejor ponelo en `true` en algun lugar que no moleste, por ejemplo en este inofensivo linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/registerLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" <-----
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_account" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/signUp_Button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Regístrate" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Gracias x la ayuda no era exactamente eso pero me sirvió para darme cuenta del problema así que muchas gracias